# Sql Case statement within Sql IN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case

I have a `sql` statement which have a where condition like below

```
WHERE (TABLE1.Field=@Id OR (@Id=0))
```

This works fine when `@Id` values is zero or more

Now I need to match multiple values when @Id value become 0.

I tried something like below which doesn't work. I know that I can use `IF-ELSE` in here, but wonder whether this can be achieve using `case` statemet

```
WHERE TABLE1.Field IN (CASE WHEN @Id>0 THEN @Id ELSE (6,16,18) END)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using an `OR`:

```
WHERE   (@Id > 0 AND Table1.Field = @Id)
OR      (@Id = 0 AND Table1.Field IN (6,16,18))
```

However, I would advise using (as you have said) `IF/ELSE`, when mashing together two conditions like this you can often force suboptimal plans. e.g In your example you could simplify this to a schema as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE T
(   ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    Field INT NOT NULL, 
    SomeOtherField INT NULL
);
GO
INSERT T  (Field)
SELECT  Number
FROM    Master..spt_values
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) t (A)
WHERE   Type = 'P'
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_T_Field ON T (Field) INCLUDE (SomeOtherField);
```

This simply populates one of the columns with the numbers 0-2047 repeated 4 times each (just for some example data). Then If I create two procedures, one that uses 'IF/ELSE' one that combines the criteria as above:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test @ID INT
AS
    SELECT  ID, Field, SomeOtherField
    FROM    T
    WHERE   (@Id > 0 AND T.Field = @Id)
    OR      (@Id = 0 AND T.Field IN (6,16,18))

GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test2 @ID INT
AS
    IF @ID = 0
        SELECT  ID, Field, SomeOtherField
        FROM    T
        WHERE   T.Field IN (6, 16, 18)
    ELSE
        SELECT  ID, Field, SomeOtherField
        FROM    T
        WHERE   T.Field = @Id
GO
```

Since compilation of queries will only happen once (unless you explicitly say otherwise), the optimiser will not pick a different plan depending on whether you pass 0 or pass an ID > 0 to the procedure, so both of the following:

```
EXECUTE dbo.Test 0;
EXECUTE dbo.Test 1;
```

Will give this plan:

[image]

The second procedure is able to estimate the best execution plan much better so running this:

```
EXECUTE dbo.Test2 0;
EXECUTE dbo.Test2 1;
```

Gives the following plan:

[image]

Real world examples will obviously vary, and I have deliberately constructed an example that proves my point. It is slightly more effort to duplicate a lot of code by using `IF/ELSE`, but it is often worth it.

Comment: Great this works fine. I cannot use `if-else` in this case this main qurey already running inder `if-else`. So if i need to use `if-else` most of the code will be duplicated.

Comment: Thats a really good example. I will compare the cost plan based on my case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE TABLE1.Field IN (case when @Id>0 THEN @Id else 6 end,
            case when @Id>0 THEN @Id else 16 end,
            case when @Id>0 THEN @Id else 18 end)
```