# using a CASE within WHERE

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, case, where-clause

I have code where I need to add filter into where clause that varies based on value of variable. As in example below if @X has a value of 0 then I want 
to include a filter for OrderID  = 10; otherwise I want to add filter for OrderID = 20 with another filter for DepartmentID either been NULL or a value of 30. This could be accomplished using a IF ELSE as below

```
DECLARE @X INT

-- Retrieve value for @X

IF @X = 0 
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM Customers
    WHERE ProductID IS NOT NULL
    AND OrderID = 10
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM Customers
    WHERE ProductID IS NOT NULL
    AND OrderID = 20 AND ( DepartmentID IS NULL OR DepartmentID = 30)
END
```

I wonder if there is someway of doing it using one SQL statement. I thought it's doable using CASE within a WHERE but SQL does not seem to allow below.

```
SELECT *
    FROM Customers
    WHERE ProductID IS NOT NULL
    AND CASE WHEN @X = 0 THEN OrderID = 10 ELSE OrderID = 20 AND ( DepartmentID IS NULL OR DepartmentID = 30) END
```

Is there anyway of accomplishing this.

Comment: Have a look [Sql Case statement within Sql IN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697049/sql-case-statement-within-sql-in)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you were close,

```
AND OrderID = (CASE WHEN @X = 0 THEN 10 ELSE 20 END)
AND DepartmentID = (CASE WHEN @X = 0 THEN DepartmentID ELSE 30 END)
```

Comment: actually missed one component in my original question of including DeparmentID also. I have updated my question now. Thanks for your prompt response

Comment: excellent. Can we include a check for either NULL or 30 in that ELSE clause?

Comment: you mean `DepartmentID IS NOT NULL AND DepartmentID = 30`?

Comment: NO, ( DepartmentID IS NULL OR DepartmentID = 30). Updated my question

Comment: you cannot use `CASE` since you want want to check for null. see guffa's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that without a `CASE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE ProductID IS NOT NULL
AND ((@X = 0 AND OrderID = 10) OR (@X <> 0 AND OrderID = 20 AND DepartmentID = 30))
```

#### Edit:

With the condition that you wanted to add:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE ProductID IS NOT NULL
AND ((@X = 0 AND OrderID = 10) OR (@X <> 0 AND OrderID = 20 AND (DepartmentID IS NULL OR DepartmentID = 30)))
```

Comment: sorry guys; had to make a change in original question. Do you mind taking a look on updated question

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE ProductID IS NOT NULL
AND OrderID = CASE WHEN @X = 0 THEN 10 ELSE 20 END
AND ISNULL(DepartmentID,30) = CASE WHEN @X = 0 THEN ISNULL(DepartmentID,30)  ELSE 30 END
```

Comment: sorry guys; had to make a change in original question. Do you mind taking a look on updated question

Comment: you are killing the index.

Comment: what to do in this type of requirement then?

Comment: I think Guffa's would be the best... I am just showing how to do it with a `CASE`.