# MsSql Server: Default bigint argument in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, arguments, default-value, coalesce

I would like to have a stored procedure with optional argument. Default value is null

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [myStoredProcedure](@itemID bigint = NULL)
```

Then I would like to use it in `COALESCE`

```
COALESCE(@itemID, table.itemID) = table.itemID
```

Is this approach correct for using optional argument? Does this work the same for Oracle?

Comment: In sake of performance it is better to do logical separation. For example IF (@itemID IS NULL ) BEGIN Statement 1 END ELSE BEGIN Statement2 END

Comment: For more information on this see [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html). [In a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18697104/1048425) I have done a worked example that elaborates on what Dmitrij has said about using `IF/EKSE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can use `COALESCE()`, I think explicit comparisons are more typical:

```
where (t.itemId = @itemId or @itemId is null)
```

Either method will work in SQL Server or Oracle because both are standard SQL.  In Oracle parameters do not start with `@` and the syntax for stored procedures can look quite different.